# Problem when trying to define an operator in Prolog

Tags: operator-overloading, prolog

I have defined a prolog file with the following code:

```
divisible(X, Y) :-
    X mod Y =:= 0.

divisibleBy(X, Y) :-
    divisible(X, Y).

op(35,xfx,divisibleBy).
```

Prolog is complaining that

> '$record_clause'/2: No permission to modify static_procedure `op/3'

What am I doing wrong? I want to define an divisibleBy operator that will allow me to write code like the following:

```
4 divisibleBy 2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use

```
:- op(35,xfx,divisibleBy).
```

`:-` tells the Prolog interpreter to *evaluate* the next term while loading the file, i.e. make a predicate call, instead of treating it as a definition (in this case a redefinition of `op/3`).

Comment: More precisely, that's called "directive" rather than "predicate call" or "predicate evaluation".

Comment: A priority of 35 is definitely not advisable for this predicate.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer given by @larsmans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3824083/4609915) is spot-on regarding your original problem.

However, you should reconsider **if** you should define a new operator.

In general, I would strongly advise against defining new operators for the following reasons:

- The gain in readability is often overrated.
- It may easily introduce new problems in places you wouldn't normally expect buggy.
- It doesn't "scale" well: a small number of operators can make code on presentation slides super-concise, but what if you add more discriminate union cases over time? More operators?

Comment: Some more advice: **If** operators are defined, they should respect the common priority levels. So if a predicate is like a comparison, (I'd say that's the example here), it should take *exactiter* the priority and fixity of `(=)/2` which is `op(700,xfx,=)`.